# Roulette Wheel for sampling user defined pdf

Tags: sampling, density-function

Following is the pdf from which I want to sample so, I used roulette wheel sampling[image: user defined pdf]

Code to generate pdf

```
pdf=np.array([1,5,1,10,1,5,1])
pdf=pdf/np.sum(pdf)
x=np.arange(0,np.size(pdf),1)
plt.bar(x,pdf)
```

Code to generate cdf

```
def pdf2cdf(tpdf):
tcdf=np.zeros_like(tpdf)
itr=0
for i in tpdf:
    tcdf[itr]=tcdf[itr-1]+tpdf[itr]
    itr=itr+1
return tcdf
cdf=pdf2cdf(pdf)
plt.bar(x,cdf)
```

CDF of the given pdf[image: CDF]

Code to sample from pdf using roulette wheel

```
lst=[]
uni=[]
for j in range(100000):
    tmp=np.random.uniform(0,1)
    uni.append(tmp)
    tmp2=np.argsort(np.abs(cdf-tmp))
    lst.append(tmp2[0])
```

histogram of uni

[image: uni]

histogram of samples drawn

[image: samples]

I don't understand what's going wrong. The pdf from which I sampled(first plot) and the histogram of samples (last plot) are not the same.
Can anybody please suggest the correction of any mistake I made above.

---

Thanks @jsk

```
for k in range(np.size(cdf)):
    if cdf[k]>tmp:
        break
tmp2=k

plt.hist(lst,bins=range(0,8), align='left', rwidth=1, normed=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the command

```py
np.argsort(np.abs(cdf-tmp)).
```

The command will find which element of the cdf is closest to tmp, regardless of whether or not tmp is greater than cdf.

According to your problem,

$P(0) = 1/24 \approx 0.04167$

$P(1) = 5/24 \approx 0.2083 $

so $ CDF(1) = 6/24 = 0.25$.

In your code, you will end up sampling a 0 if tmp is closer to 0.04167 than 0.25, for example tmp = 0.1 will return a 0, which means that you are assigning 0 a much higher proportion of the time than 0.04167.  What range of values for tmp will ensure that you assign a 0 with probability 0.04167?  What range of values for tmp will ensure that you will assign a 1 with the appropriate probability?

I will leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to adjust your code in light of the problem I have identified with the current code.